# What are disadvantages of using Lombok in my Spring Boot RestApi?

Tags: spring-boot, lombok

I am using Lombok in my Spring Boot Rest Api. I searched a lot but could not found what I want to know about Lombok. My rest api is an enterprise level application which would be extend with more modules in future.

Should I use lombok? What are the major disadvantages of Lombok using in enterprise application?

My IDE is STS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no special advantages or disadvantages of using Lombok in an enterprise application. Lombok itself and all its annotations are removed during compilation, so there will be no additional libraries at runtime.

Furthermore, if at any point later you'd decide against Lombok, you could remove it again by running `delombok`, which will give you the code that Lombok generates. So there is no real risk there (besides that it will of course take some time to delombok everything).

For a general (of course opinion-based) discussion on Lombok's (dis)advantages, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852091/is-it-safe-to-use-project-lombok/12807937#12807937).

Answer (score 1):

You have to know what Lombok really does under the hood.

For example, Lombok adds `@java.beans.ConstructorProperties` before constructors. This may be important if you use Jackson serialization.

See https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor